# jquery- open and check radio button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I have some radio buttons to filter data on my webpage that are working absolutely fine for me but i am failed to perform check on that radio button...

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="scat" value="1" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&scat=bank-manager'>
<label for="radio1">bank manager</label><br><br>

<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="scat" value="1" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&scat=ceo'>
<label for="radio2">ceo</label><br><br>

<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="scat" value="1" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&scat=company-head'>
<label for="radio3">company head</label>
```

I use jquery to open and perform check on radio button click.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        window.location=$(this).attr('data-href');
    });
    // parse the url:
    var scat = window.location.search.match(/scat=(\w+)/)[1];
    if (typeof scat !== 'undefined') {
        // update the correct radio button:
        $('input[value="' + scat + '"]').prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

On using above query if i click on "ceo" radio button, It works for me absolutely fine i.e. it filters content for me and performs check also...
on the other hand if i click on bank manager or company head. It only filters content ..it dosen't perform check...Any help ??

Thanks in advance...

**Note:** data-href includes url having "-" in bank manager and company head and in label field both bank manager and company head are without "-".

Comment: Why is there `&&` in the data-href` also shouldn't it be `/subcat` not `/scat` in the regex

Comment: and how i can do it without "&&"....as i want to show scat value in url...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `&` (You have incorrect notation used in URL i.e. &&) value as an `data` attribute as follows,

You have currently as ,

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="scat" value="1" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&scat=bank-manager'>
<label for="radio1">bank manager</label><br><br>
```

Add `data-scat` attribute to fetch `scat` value and also to be able to get clicked based on `value`,

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="scat" value="bank-manager" data-scat="bank-manager" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz'>
<label for="radio1">bank manager</label><br><br>
```

And in jQuery you should access it as follows and append in your URL,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
       window.location=$(this).data('href')+"&scat="+$(this).data('scat');
    });

    // parse the url:
    var hrefLink = window.location.search;
    // update the correct radio button:
    $('input[value=' + hrefLink.substring(hrefLink.indexOf("scat")+5) + ']').prop("checked", true);
 // } Commenting an extra closed bracket
 });
```

Comment: can you show me what all you tried? Also you get href using data('href') but not data('scat')?

Comment: I have tried...

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        window.location==$(this).data('href')+"&scat="+$(this).data('scat');
    });
    // parse the url:
    var scat = window.location.search.match(/scat=(\w+)/)[1];
    if (typeof scat !== 'undefined') {
        // update the correct radio button:
        $('input[value="' + scat + '"]').prop("checked", true);
    }
});

Comment: What this does? .match(/scat=(\w+)/)[1]?

Comment: Don't have knowledge about jquery...juz wanna perform this task...So as i got from somewhere i juz used it...

Comment: That's why i asked you. Anyway why you are doing check? just to check if href is present? and why you want to check the radio? when you click on the radio it will checked automatically

Comment: How ?? Can you please write a fiddle or write here in answers for me...??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130769/discussion-between-scanqr-and-ashish).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex need to be modified to fetch `-`, also need to change the selector to attribute ends with selector

```js
var search = "?cat=xyz&scat=bank-manager"; //replace with window.location.search
var scat = search.match(/scat=([\w-]+)/);
if (scat && scat[1]) {
  // update the correct radio button:
  $('input[data-href$=' + scat[1] + ']').prop("checked", true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="scat" value="1" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&scat=bank-manager'>
<label for="radio1">bank manager</label>
<br>
<br>

<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="scat" value="1" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&scat=ceo'>
<label for="radio2">ceo</label>
<br>
<br>

<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="scat" value="1" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&scat=company-head'>
<label for="radio3">company head</label>
```

Comment: it is performing check...but doesn't filtering data for me...simply it is not opening data-href link....

Comment: In above code you have replaced window.location.search with var search....but in my code both cat and scat values are url post variables....How i can pass these in jquery.... ??

Comment: @Ashish `$('input[data-href$=' + scat[1] + ']').prop("checked", true).triggerhandler('click');`

Comment: not working sir...may be i am doing something wrong...May i have complete jquery code...i will be very thankful to you...

Comment: Its redirecting perfectly...but not performing check not even on without "-" values.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specify the correct value to your radio input tags and you are using value in jQuery selector.Just add the right value to it and it will work fine.

It should be

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="scat" value="bank-manager" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&subcat=bank-manager'>
```

insted of

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="scat" value="1" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&subcat=bank-manager'>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
  });
  // parse the url:
  var search = "vlist.php?cat=xyz&subcat=company-head";
  // uncomment this line and comment below one  
  // var scat = window.location.search.match(/bcat=([\w-]+)/)[1];
  var scat = search.match(/bcat=([\w-]+)/)[1];
  if (typeof scat !== 'undefined') {
    // update the correct radio button:
    $('input[value="' + scat + '"]').prop("checked", true);
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="scat" value="bank-manager" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&subcat=bank-manager'>
<label for="radio1">bank manager</label>
<br>
<br>

<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="scat" value="ceo" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&subcat=ceo'>
<label for="radio2">ceo</label>
<br>
<br>

<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="scat" value="company-head" data-href='vlist.php?cat=xyz&&subcat=company-head'>
<label for="radio3">company head</label>
```

Comment: Have you change this line var scat = search.match(/bcat=([\w-]+)/)[1]; to 
var scat = window.location.search.match(/bcat=([\w-]+)/)[1];

Comment: Use console.log() to check the value of scat and make sure that it get the desired value (bank-manager,ceo,company-head).